# SQL CASE statement that's not a waterfall grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 categories:

```
categories   number_units
CAT_A        10 
CAT_B        20
CAT_C        30
```

If I do a GROUP BY for column `categories` I will get the 3 categories seen above. But if I want to do a case statement like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN categories LIKE 'CAT%' ...
```

(to show the sum of all those that contain CAT it will exclude the groupings like CAT_A, _B, _C)

How can I write a query that will get the following result:

```
categories   sum
CAT          60
CAT_A        10
CAT_B        20
CAT_C        30
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Use `rollup` in sql

Comment: hi, you could group by the expression you're interested in

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 5):

Many databases support the standard `grouping sets` functionality:

```
select coalesce(category, 'CAT'), sum(number_of_units)
from t
group by grouping sets ((), category);
```

Comment: Is the a way of showing 2 groupings. Like if I want to GROUP everything with CAT then grouping any values in that column regardless if it had CAT or not?

Comment: Good one! What's the difference between this and rollup?

Comment: @banana_99 . . . `GROUPING SETS` let's you specify exactly what columns you want groups.  `ROLLUP` implements a hierarchical set, so it is not as flexible.

Answer (score 3):

I think `with rollup` is your bet option. (In this scenario `with cube` would also return same result)

```
 create table cat(categories varchar(50),   number_units int);
 insert into cat values('CAT_A',        10);
 insert into cat values('CAT_B',        20);
 insert into cat values('CAT_C',        30);
```

Query:

```
 select Coalesce(categories,'CAT')categories   ,sum(number_units) [sum] 
 from cat 
 group by categories with rollup
 order by categories

 GO
```

Output:

| categories | sum |
| --- | --- |
| CAT | 60 |
| CAT_A | 10 |
| CAT_B | 20 |
| CAT_C | 30 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05b1d1f1cd4fff6ce20f4c3babb13715)*